# why angular2 service is getting called multiple time?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service ( `MyService` ) which i included in my project module. 
And I am creating a private variable of type `MyService` in each of my component to set and get data in that service.

In my console log I see the same service is getting called multiple times.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    MyService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})


//Here is my Component code which create a private variable in my component

@Component({
  selector: 'summary',
  templateUrl: 'summary.component.html'
})
export class SummaryComponent extends OnInit {

  constructor(
              private myService: MyService,
              ) {
    super();
  }
```

How I to stop object creation multiple time?

Comment: Where is the code calling the service? What method is called several times? How many summary components are on your page?

Comment: I just given one component here and there are many components like that . In my application in each component MyService type variable is created and injected in constructor as given in the code.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shared module for the service activation, that way there is only one instance of the service at a atime.

See my answer at [Can't load shared directives of a NgModule in other NgModules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278573/cant-load-shared-directives-of-a-ngmodule-in-other-ngmodules/39278695#39278695) for an idea of how to implement the shared module.