# Angular2 - Registering a directive at app level

Tags: angular, polymer, angular2-directives

I am trying to register a few commonly used directives in my main module in order to be able to use them across all the submodules and only have one copy of them.

My problem is that for some reason, the directive only gets recognized in the declared components of the main module but none of the child modules get to use it.

Am i doing something wrong? Is there a Angular concept i am missing here? This is the main module and a simple directive i try to use in the child modules imported in the main module.

I am not getting any error or any indication i am doing something wrong. For the sake of keeping it short, i edited out some of the import. Let me know if there is something else i should add.

Directive:

```
import {Directive, OnChanges, Input, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector:'[readonlyCustom]'
})
export class ReadonlyDirective implements OnChanges{
    @Input('readonlyCustom') val: boolean;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngOnChanges(c){
        if(c && c.val  && c.val.currentValue === true){
            this.el.nativeElement.readonly = c.val.currentValue;
        }
        else if(c && c.val  && c.val.currentValue === false){
            this.el.nativeElement.readonly = c.val.currentValue;
        }
    }
}
```

AppModule.ts

```
/* .... A bunch of imports... */
import {PolymerElement} from "@vaadin/angular2-polymer";
import {ReadonlyDirective} from "./shared/directives/readonlyDirective";



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   /*some other declarations */

    ReadonlyDirective 
  ],
  imports: [
   /* ... some module imports ....*/
   /* ... child modules ....*/
    UsersModule,
    RolesModule,
    OrgModule,
    GroupsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents:[/*some components*/],
  providers: [/*some services*/],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent], 

  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Edit: I am using Polymer components inside my app and using Angular2-polymer from Vaadin.
It seems that i need to mention the PolymerElement("polymer-element-name") in each module in order for data binding to be recognized. Is it possible to do it at app level also?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer with the help of [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) who was kind enough to edit his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560817/how-to-make-directives-and-components-available-globally?rq=1#37560885).

I also found another question answer that helped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278573/cant-load-shared-directives-of-a-ngmodule-in-other-ngmodules?rq=1).